# Como crear una platilla PDF para C#?

Tags: c#

Quisiera saber si es posible utilizar plantillas de documentos PDF, previamente estructurados y abrirlos a través de Código de C# reemplazar partes del mismo por los resultados que necesito.

Por ejemplo
una tabla en PDF que por nombre lleva {{Nombre_Table}} está parte me gustaría reemplazarla por ejemplo con el resultado de una operación.

Nunca lo he realizado en C#, solo lo he realizado para PHP y tratando utilizar el mismo código no se puede ejecutar en C#.

Se que existe la librería iTextSharp para C# pero los resultados que necesito son más ha producir un reporte mas profesional.

Alguien sabe como solucionar mi problema!

Comment: Yo hago las plantillas en word , las edito con la biblioteca spiredoc : https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-doc-component.html#.Xp8nStNKjOQ y las exporto a pdf. Tienen para editar pdf pero no la he probado.

Comment: A que te refieres con mas profesional ItextSharp brinda reportes bastante descentes solo debes invertir tiempo en los ajustes. Agrega un ejemplo del reporte de salida que quieres y como estas tratando de implememntarlo